# How to calculate yesterdays date without using 'Date' in bash? (MacOS)

Tags: bash, macos, date, scripting, date-arithmetic

Wondering how one would calculate yesterdays date without the usage of 'date' in bash (MacOS).

This includes leap years of course to prevent errors etc.

Would this be doable without MAJOR investment?

If anyone has implemented this for whatever reason, I would gladly like to take a look. :)

Comment: What's the point of that constraint?

Comment: There really is none. I am just curious in the solution

Comment: I think this is correct but can't test till month-end :-) `perl -MPOSIX -le ' @now = localtime; $now[3] -= 1; print scalar localtime mktime @now'`

Comment: **Perl** is included on all macOS versions, by the way.

Comment: Ah damn that's cheating as well! :D Sorry my bad, should have mentioned that I wanted to see functions & all :)

Like calculating the day, checking what day was yesterday, and if today is 1th of the month, how many days did last month have, etc